# Antd Select form item keyboard behavior problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a form which for the most part works fine. But one thing bugs me about it is the Select item for imputing a person's state (see screenshot below). It works fine with the mouse, but if you're tabbing through the form and tab to the State field, then type a state like "CA" for California, then tab to the next field (zipcode), the State field resets to blank. I would like it to stay populated with CA if it matched one of the selector's options.

It *does* work if i type "CA" and hit enter to advance to the next field, but that doesn't seem intuitive as to how forms normally work. It also works if I just use my mouse to select the field. I've been looking over the antd documentation on a Select and don't see anything jumping out at me that might control this. Maybe i'm missing something and i need to do some kind of onchange function?

Anyways, seems like a fairly simple problem but the solution is eluding me.

[image: Example]

The select form item's code:

```js
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "state"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "state"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Select
                                  showSearch
                                  placeholder="State"
                                  defaultActiveFirstOption={true}
                                >
                                  <Option value="AL">AL</Option>
                                  <Option value="AK">AK</Option>
                                  <Option value="AZ">AZ</Option>
                                  <Option value="AR">AR</Option>
                                  <Option value="CA">CA</Option>
                                  <Option value="CO">CO</Option>
                                  <Option value="CT">CT</Option>
                                  <Option value="DE">DE</Option>
                                  <Option value="FL">FL</Option>
                                  <Option value="GL">GA</Option>
                                  <Option value="HI">HI</Option>
                                  <Option value="ID">ID</Option>
                                  <Option value="IL">IL</Option>
                                  <Option value="IN">IN</Option>
                                  <Option value="IA">IA</Option>
                                  <Option value="KS">KS</Option>
                                  <Option value="KY">KY</Option>
                                  <Option value="LA">LA</Option>
                                  <Option value="ME">ME</Option>
                                  <Option value="MD">MD</Option>
                                  <Option value="MA">MA</Option>
                                  <Option value="MI">MI</Option>
                                  <Option value="MN">MN</Option>
                                  <Option value="MS">MS</Option>
                                  <Option value="MO">MO</Option>
                                  <Option value="MT">MT</Option>
                                  <Option value="NE">NE</Option>
                                  <Option value="NV">NV</Option>
                                  <Option value="NH">NH</Option>
                                  <Option value="NJ">NJ</Option>
                                  <Option value="NM">NM</Option>
                                  <Option value="NY">NY</Option>
                                  <Option value="NC">NC</Option>
                                  <Option value="ND">ND</Option>
                                  <Option value="OH">OH</Option>
                                  <Option value="OK">OK</Option>
                                  <Option value="OR">OR</Option>
                                  <Option value="PA">PA</Option>
                                  <Option value="RI">RI</Option>
                                  <Option value="SC">SC</Option>
                                  <Option value="SD">SD</Option>
                                  <Option value="TN">TN</Option>
                                  <Option value="TX">TX</Option>
                                  <Option value="UT">UT</Option>
                                  <Option value="VT">VT</Option>
                                  <Option value="VA">VA</Option>
                                  <Option value="WA">WA</Option>
                                  <Option value="WV">WV</Option>
                                  <Option value="WI">WI</Option>
                                  <Option value="WY">WY</Option>
                                  <Option value="AS">AS</Option>
                                  <Option value="DC">DC</Option>
                                  <Option value="FM">FM</Option>
                                  <Option value="GU">GU</Option>
                                  <Option value="MH">MH</Option>
                                  <Option value="MP">MP</Option>
                                  <Option value="PW">PW</Option>
                                  <Option value="PR">PR</Option>
                                  <Option value="VI">VI</Option>
                                </Select>
                              </Form.Item>
```

**Update #1**

So following the suggestions in the comments (and my noticing a similar approach [here](https://ant.design/components/form/v3#Replace-validateFieldsAndScroll-with-scrollToField) under the form control section), to my class i've added a `formRef = React.createRef();`.

Then in my Form tag I added a `ref={this.formRef}` tag. Then modified my Select by adding an onBlur tag that triggers setFieldsValue to set the uppercase version of the input.

This compiles and runs fine. It even outputs the console.log statement. But it does not set the field value for some reason and i'm not sure why.

```js
    return (
      <Form
**      ref={this.formRef}
        name="dynamic_form_item"
        {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        id="myForm"
        validateMessages={validateMessages}
      >
        {
          <Form.List name="applicants">
            {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {fields.map((field, index) => (
                    <Form.Item {...formItemLayout} label={`Applicant #${index + 1}`} key={field.key}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "state"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "state"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Select
                                  showSearch
                                  placeholder="State"
                                  defaultActiveFirstOption={true}
**                                onBlur={(event) => {
**                                  console.log("onblur: ", event);
**                                  this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({ state: event.target.value.toUpperCase() });
**                                }}
                                >
```

**Update #2**

screenshot of values when onFinish is called. Note this is a dynamic form where user can add additional applicants by clicking an add applicant button. Each applicant has the fields shown including the state they live in.

```
    const onFinish = (values) => {
      console.log("onFinish: ", values);
      this.props.onSubmit({
        applicants: values.applicants,
      });
    };
```

[image]

**Update #3**

Tried to mimic the approach however for some reason in the object being returned by values, state is absent and ultimately i'm getting an uncaught typeerror and state doesn't populate.

[image]

```
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "state"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "state"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Select
                                  showSearch
                                  placeholder="State"
                                  defaultActiveFirstOption={true}
                                  onBlur={(event) => {
                                    console.log("values", this.formRef.current.getFieldsValue());
                                    console.log("target:", event.target);
                                    console.log("id", event.target.id);
                                    const stateIndex = event.target.getAttribute("aria-activedescendant").split("_").slice(-1);
                                    const values = this.formRef.current.getFieldsValue();
                                    const namePath = event.target.id.split("_");
                                    console.log("namePath", namePath);
                                    values[namePath[0]][namePath[1]][namePath[2]] = event.target.value.toUpperCase() || STATES[stateIndex];
                                    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue(values);
                                  }}
                                >
                                  {STATES.map((state) => (
                                    <Option value={state} key={state}>
                                      {state}
                                    </Option>
                                  ))}
                                </Select>
                              </Form.Item>
```

**Update #4**

So sure enough, removal of the name property in the Form tag resolved the above issue and it's working as expected without error.

In the interest of wrapping up this question in hopes it may help someone else, I wanted to capture the solution. Ultimately the solution amounted to making it so when the user tabs out of the field in question, the field's value gets set to what the user typed. This was done by adding the onBlur tag to my antd Select tag. onBlur fires when the user tabs out of the field. Then making it set the field to the characters entered. Which turned out to be more complicated then I would've thought due to my use of a dyanmic form and nested object array (applicants).

Note the state now shows up under value and the namepath matches what the code expects.

[image]

My final code up until this point looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, Col, Row, Select, Button } from "antd";
import { PlusOutlined, MinusCircleTwoTone } from "@ant-design/icons";

const InputGroup = Input.Group;
const Option = Select.Option;
const { TextArea } = Input;
const maxApplicants = 4;

const rules = [{ required: true }];

const STATES = [
  "AL",
  "AK",
  "AZ",
  "AR",
  "CA",
  "CO",
  "CT",
  "DE",
  "DC",
  "FM",
  "FL",
  "GA",
  "GU",
  "HI",
  "ID",
  "IL",
  "IN",
  "IA",
  "KS",
  "KY",
  "LA",
  "ME",
  "MH",
  "MD",
  "MA",
  "MI",
  "MN",
  "MS",
  "MO",
  "MT",
  "NE",
  "NV",
  "NH",
  "NJ",
  "NM",
  "NY",
  "NC",
  "ND",
  "MP",
  "OH",
  "OK",
  "OR",
  "PW",
  "PA",
  "PR",
  "RI",
  "SC",
  "SD",
  "TN",
  "TX",
  "UT",
  "VT",
  "VI",
  "VA",
  "WA",
  "WV",
  "WI",
  "WY",
];

const validateMessages = {
  required: "Required!",
  types: {
    email: "Invalid E-mail!",
    number: "Invalid Number!",
  },
  number: {
    range: "Must be between ${min} and ${max}",
  },
};

const formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 6 },
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 36 },
    sm: { span: 16 },
  },
};

const formItemLayoutWithOutLabel = {
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 36, offset: 0 },
    sm: { span: 16, offset: 6 },
  },
};

export default class TenantForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      applicants: [
        {
          firstName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.first : "",
          middleName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.middle : "",
          lastName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.last : "",
          street: props.tenant ? props.tenant.street : "",
          city: props.tenant ? props.tenant.city : "",
          state: props.tenant ? props.tenant.state : "",
          zipcode: props.tenant ? props.tenant.zipcode : "",
        },
      ],
      error: "",
    };
  }

  formRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    const onFinish = (values) => {
      console.log("onFinish: ", values);
      this.props.onSubmit({
        applicants: values.applicants,
      });
    };

    return (
      <Form
        ref={this.formRef}
        {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        id="myForm"
        validateMessages={validateMessages}
        initialValues={{ applicants: [{ firstName: "" }] }}
      >
        {
          <Form.List name="applicants">
            {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {fields.map((field, index) => (
                    <Form.Item {...formItemLayout} label={`Applicant #${index + 1}`} key={field.key}>
                      <Row key={field.key} gutter={[0, 8]} justify="start">
                        <Col>
                          <Row gutter={[4, 4]}>
                            <Col span={7}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "firstName"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "firstName"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={7}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "middleName"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "middleName"]} initialValue="">
                                <Input placeholder="Middle Name" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={9}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "lastName"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "lastName"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col flex="none">
                              {index > 0 ? (
                                <MinusCircleTwoTone
                                  className="dynamic-delete-button"
                                  onClick={() => {
                                    remove(field.name);
                                  }}
                                />
                              ) : null}
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                          <Row gutter={[4, 4]}>
                            <Col span={23}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "address"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "address"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="Address" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                          <Row gutter={[4, 4]}>
                            <Col span={12}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "city"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "city"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="City" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={5}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "state"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "state"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Select
                                  showSearch
                                  placeholder="State"
                                  defaultActiveFirstOption={true}
                                  onBlur={(event) => {
                                    console.log("values", this.formRef.current.getFieldsValue());
                                    console.log("target:", event.target);
                                    console.log("id", event.target.id);
                                    const stateIndex = event.target.getAttribute("aria-activedescendant").split("_").slice(-1);
                                    const values = this.formRef.current.getFieldsValue();
                                    const namePath = event.target.id.split("_");
                                    console.log("namePath", namePath);
                                    values[namePath[0]][namePath[1]][namePath[2]] = event.target.value.toUpperCase() || STATES[stateIndex];
                                    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue(values);
                                  }}
                                >
                                  {STATES.map((state) => (
                                    <Option value={state} key={state}>
                                      {state}
                                    </Option>
                                  ))}
                                </Select>
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={6}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "zipcode"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "zipcode"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="Zip Code" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Form.Item>
                  ))}
                  <Form.Item>
                    {console.log("count:", fields.length)}
                    {fields.length < maxApplicants ? (
                      <Button
                        type="dashed"
                        onClick={() => {
                          add();
                        }}
                        style={{ width: "100%" }}
                      >
                        <PlusOutlined /> Add Applicant
                      </Button>
                    ) : null}
                  </Form.Item>
                </div>
              );
            }}
          </Form.List>
        }
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is use `onBlur` on the Select component in combination with `form.setFieldsValue`.

See codesandbox below:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/distracted-platform-pvdiz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks I can see that it works but struggling to make it work in my application. I see that onBlur is apparently a tag that triggers when you tab out of the field. I see that setFieldsValue then sets the field to it's contents. How do you make this work in a class component?

Comment: It would work the same way in a class component, but you would gain access to the form instance via a ref: `formRef = React.createRef();`

See line 24 and line 49 here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xwqju?file=/index.js:391-422

If my answer has helped you out, I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as useful. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks I've updated my question to reflect what I've done so far. While it compiles and runs fine and is clearly calling the onBlur as desired, it doesn't set the field as expected.

Comment: In your `onFinish` handler could you console.log `values` and post the result. I believe the `state` field isn't being set properly because `state` isn't a top-level property inside of `values` object. This `name={[field.name, "state"]}` seems to indicate `state` is nested inside of a property that evaluates to `field.name`.

Comment: Added screenshot of console.log of ```values``` in Update #2 above. Perhaps I should've mentioned it's a dynamic form with multiple applicants. Each applicant has a name, address, city, state, etc. I was trying to keep the original question simple :(

Comment: Updated solution for dynamic form: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wilson-tr5wx?file=/index.js

Comment: Tried mimic'ing the approach but something is off. interesting how much more complex this is then I thought when I initially asked about it. Yikes!

Comment: Could you include the code blocks that contain `Form` and `Form.List` components? It looks like you probably have a `name` prop defined in both components, and because the `name` value has underscores, my `split` method is failing to work. Yeah. It's pretty crazy how complex this is getting, but I luckily once you secure the behavior you want, you can wrap the component in a HOC to make the behavior reusable in future components.

Comment: By the way, I think your current attempt at implementing my approach would work if you removed the `name` prop on your `Form` component. I'm pretty sure you only need to give a `name` prop to `Form` if you intend to access the form instance via `Form.Provider` elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Like magic, that worked! I see how it changes namePath and ultimately enables it to change the value. Wow, thanks so much. You're my hero! I learned a bunch of things trying to figure out what seemed like a simple problem initially. Use of onblur, getfieldsvalue, setfieldsvalue, createref, and getattribute. As my first go at creating a dynamic form, it's interesting how all this is affected by that too. Next step, figure out how to only set the typed in characters if they match the list of state options :). Anyways, i'm going to mark this as solved and summarize the solution to help others.

Comment: I tried breaking my form into subforms by pulling the dynamic applicants form out inspired by [this article](https://www.sicara.ai/blog/2018-06-27-custom-nested-validated-forms-with-react) and broke it (the form works, the state populating via keyboard doesn't). uhg. the ref becomes either null or undefined in the child component and I'm not exactly sure what to do about it. Tried a few things like passing it as a prop but to no avail.