# Antd Select Form Item keyboard behavior problem in dynamic nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-forwardref

I have a nested dynamic form.

Currently if I input something in the city field, then tab to the state field and type two letters for a state, then tab to the next field, the state field does not stay populated. I would like it to stay populated with my state. Pretty simple common behavior. Example screenshots:

[image: Before]

As soon as I tab to the next field, State returns to blank:

[image: After]

I believe that essentially the way to do this is to use the Select element's onblur option to populate it when the user tabs out. In fact I used to have it working when it was not a nested component [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822119/antd-select-form-item-keyboard-behavior-problem). Unfortunately when I refactored it to make it nested, i broke it. I think my ref broke and I can't figure out how to use forwardref to fix it but i could be way off here. refs kind of make my head spin.

Hoping some kind soul out there will help me understand how to fix it. I'm also now getting a warning that each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop and am unsure why.

**Parent Component TenantForm.js**

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import { Form, Input, Select } from "antd";
import ArrayOfSubFormComponentsForApplicants from "./ArrayOfSubFormComponentsForApplicants";

const rules = [{ required: true }];

const validateMessages = {
  required: "Required!",
  types: {
    email: "Invalid E-mail!",
    number: "Invalid Number!",
  },
  number: {
    range: "Must be between ${min} and ${max}",
  },
};

const formItemLayoutWithOutLabel = {
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 36, offset: 0 },
    sm: { span: 16, offset: 6 },
  },
};

export default class TenantForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tenant: {
        applicants: [
          {
            firstName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.first : "",
            middleName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.middle : "",
            lastName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.last : "",
            street: props.tenant ? props.tenant.street : "",
            city: props.tenant ? props.tenant.city : "",
            state: props.tenant ? props.tenant.state : "",
            zipcode: props.tenant ? props.tenant.zipcode : "",
          },
        ],
        error: "",
      }
    };
  }  
    
  handleFieldChange = (field) => (event, value, selectedKey) => {
    // make a copy of the object first to avoid changes by reference
    let data = { ...this.state.data };  
  
    // use here event or value of selectedKey depending on your component's event
    data[field] = value;  
  
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    const onFinish = (values) => {
      console.log("onFinish: ", values);
      this.props.onSubmit({
        applicants: values.applicants,
      });
    };
    return (
      <Form
        {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        id="myForm"
        validateMessages={validateMessages}
        initialValues={{ applicants: [{ firstName: "" }] }}
      >
        <ArrayOfSubFormComponentsForApplicants
          value={this.state.tenant.applicants}
          onChange={this.handleFieldChange('applicants')}
        />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Component ArrayOfSubFormComponentsForApplicants.js**

```
import React from "react";
import SubFormComponentForApplicants from './SubFormComponentForApplicants';

export default class ArrayOfSubFormComponentsForApplicants extends React.Component {
  
  handleFieldChange = (index) => (event, value, selectedKey) => {
    let data = [...this.props.value];
    data[index] = value;
    this.props.onChange(null, data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.value.map((subform, index) =>
          <SubFormComponentForApplicants
            key={subform.key}
            value={subform}
            onChange={this.handleFieldChange(index)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ArrayOfSubFormComponentsForApplicants
```

**Child Component SubFormComponentForApplicants.js**

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import { Form, Input, Col, Row, Select, Button, DatePicker, Switch } from "antd";
import { PlusOutlined, DeleteTwoTone } from "@ant-design/icons";

const InputGroup = Input.Group;
const Option = Select.Option;
const { TextArea } = Input;
const maxApplicants = 4;

const rules = [{ required: true }];

const STATES = [
  "AL",
  "AK",
  "AZ",
  "AR",
  "CA",
  "CO",
  "CT",
  "DE",
  "DC",
  "FM",
  "FL",
  "GA",
  "GU",
  "HI",
  "ID",
  "IL",
  "IN",
  "IA",
  "KS",
  "KY",
  "LA",
  "ME",
  "MH",
  "MD",
  "MA",
  "MI",
  "MN",
  "MS",
  "MO",
  "MT",
  "NE",
  "NV",
  "NH",
  "NJ",
  "NM",
  "NY",
  "NC",
  "ND",
  "MP",
  "OH",
  "OK",
  "OR",
  "PW",
  "PA",
  "PR",
  "RI",
  "SC",
  "SD",
  "TN",
  "TX",
  "UT",
  "VT",
  "VI",
  "VA",
  "WA",
  "WV",
  "WI",
  "WY",
];

const validateMessages = {
  required: "Required!",
  types: {
    email: "Invalid E-mail!",
    number: "Invalid Number!",
  },
  number: {
    range: "Must be between ${min} and ${max}",
  },
};

const formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 6 },
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 36 },
    sm: { span: 16 },
  },
};

const formItemLayoutWithOutLabel = {
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 36, offset: 0 },
    sm: { span: 16, offset: 6 },
  },
};

class SubFormComponentForApplicants extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      applicants: [
        {
          firstName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.first : "",
          middleName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.middle : "",
          lastName: props.tenant ? props.tenant.last : "",
          street: props.tenant ? props.tenant.street : "",
          city: props.tenant ? props.tenant.city : "",
          state: props.tenant ? props.tenant.state : "",
          zipcode: props.tenant ? props.tenant.zipcode : "",
        },
      ],
      error: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <Form.List name="applicants">
            {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {fields.map((field, index) => (
                    <Form.Item {...formItemLayout} label={`Applicant #${index + 1}`} key={field.key}>
                      <Row key={field.key} gutter={[0, 8]} justify="start">
                        <Col>
                          <Row gutter={[4, 4]}>
                            <Col span={7}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "firstName"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "firstName"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={7}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "middleName"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "middleName"]} initialValue="">
                                <Input placeholder="Middle Name" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={9}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "lastName"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "lastName"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col flex="none">
                              {index > 0 ? (
                                <DeleteTwoTone
                                  className="dynamic-delete-button"
                                  onClick={() => {
                                    remove(field.name);
                                  }}
                                />
                              ) : null}
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                          <Row gutter={[4, 4]}>
                            <Col span={23}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "address"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "address"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="Address" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                          <Row gutter={[4, 4]}>
                            <Col span={12}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "city"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "city"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="City" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={5}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "state"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "state"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Select
                                  showSearch
                                  placeholder="State"
                                  defaultActiveFirstOption={true}
                                >
                                  {STATES.map((state) => (
                                    <Option value={state} key={state}>
                                      {state}
                                    </Option>
                                  ))}
                                </Select>
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={6}>
                              <Form.Item name={[field.name, "zipcode"]} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "zipcode"]} rules={rules}>
                                <Input placeholder="Zip Code" />
                              </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Form.Item>
                  ))}
                  <Form.Item>
                    {fields.length < maxApplicants ? (
                      <Button
                        type="dashed"
                        onClick={() => {
                          add();
                        }}
                        style={{ width: "100%" }}
                      >
                        <PlusOutlined /> Add Applicant
                      </Button>
                    ) : null}
                  </Form.Item>
                </div>
              );
            }}
          </Form.List>
    );
  }
}

export default SubFormComponentForApplicants;
```

Comment: Have you tried using the onChange events of the form fields?

Comment: Why are you nesting your array in tenant?

Comment: My tenant object is going to be rather complex. Within a tenant object, I have an applicants object (of which there can be several), children object (of which there can be several), pets object (of which there can be several), some other variables like date created/status/etc, and a leases object (which can have many). I could put all this in one js file and form but my thought is by nesting it i can reuse the component for applicants, children, pets, leases elsewhere in the app. But given i've dug myself into a hole trying to do this lately i'm strongly tempted to just give up on the nesting.

Comment: and if i need to reuse something like the form code for applicants again elsewhere (which i will), i'll just cut/paste it rather then trying to break it out as a reusable component.

Comment: any chance to get a codesandbox for this?

Comment: I copied your code over to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64072093-3vxcw?file=/src/App.tsx) and it seems to be working fine?